# three tables side by side with Table Threeparttable Resizebox and build in Tablenotes

Tags: tables, threeparttable, tablenotes

I am trying to make a table with three subtables side by side using the threeparttable environment within a table environment since I would like to have build in table notes and I need a resizebox. However the table notes are cutoff in the middle of the table. Is there a way to use threeparttable and create two, three or more subtables and appropriate table notes without manually creating text under a table? Here is my code:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\caption{Caption of the Table}  
\begin{threeparttable}[]
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{lccccc} \hline \hline
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Subtable Name} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
LOSSFNK & 0.648* & 0.613 & 0.724** & 0.648* & 1.255 \\
& (0.337) & (0.580) & (0.360) & (0.364) & (1.053) \\
Observations & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 \\
R-squared & 0.047 & 0.051 & 0.050 & 0.049 & 0.055 \\ 
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
LOSSFNK & 0.050** & 0.048* & 0.051** & 0.047** & 0.021 \\
& (0.021) & (0.028) & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.041) \\
Observations & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 \\
R-squared & 0.080 & 0.083 & 0.082 & 0.081 & 0.086 \\        
& & & & & \\ \hline 
& & & & & \\ 
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ \hline \hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{lccccc} \hline \hline
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Subtable Name} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
LOSSFNK & 0.457 & -0.318 & 0.570* & 0.649* & 1.011 \\
& (0.309) & (0.535) & (0.325) & (0.348) & (0.806) \\
Observations & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 \\
R-squared & 0.045 & 0.049 & 0.048 & 0.047 & 0.053 \\ 
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
LOSSFNK & 0.044** & 0.020 & 0.042** & 0.046** & -0.017 \\
& (0.019) & (0.022) & (0.019) & (0.022) & (0.027) \\
Observations & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 \\
R-squared & 0.084 & 0.087 & 0.086 & 0.085 & 0.091 \\    
& & & & & \\ \hline 
& & & & & \\    
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ \hline \hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{lccccc} \hline \hline
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Subtable Name} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
LOSSFNK & 0.066 & -0.777 & 0.182 & 0.481 & 1.795 \\
& (0.467) & (0.856) & (0.486) & (0.549) & (1.263) \\
Observations & 204,520 & 204,520 & 204,520 & 204,520 & 204,520 \\
R-squared & 0.028 & 0.036 & 0.033 & 0.032 & 0.045 \\ 
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
LOSSFNK & 0.045** & 0.044 & 0.044** & 0.044* & 0.048 \\
& (0.021) & (0.032) & (0.021) & (0.024) & (0.052) \\
Observations & 261,101 & 261,101 & 261,101 & 261,101 & 261,101 \\
R-squared & 0.062 & 0.069 & 0.065 & 0.065 & 0.075 \\    
& & & & & \\ \hline
& & & & & \\ 
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ \hline \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{threeparttable}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item There should be some table notes here that go across all three subtables and not cutoff in the middle 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

## Edit:

thanks a lot for the suggestions. I managed to use the example 1 from leandriis after making some minor changes since I am using kpfonts which is a bit smaller.

Here are some of my answers:

What I was trying to achieve is having three tables next to each other and having one caption and the same table notes. Since I am producing results from stata I wanted to have a somewhat automated process for creating a table. 
I wanted to use a `threeparttable` because I thought it is the easiest and fastest way to have a structured table with build in table notes in the right format etc and not having to try out different font sizes and position of text under the table. And since it was too big for the page I used `resizebox`.

When is a good situation to use `threeparttable`? And what are `\tnote` directives?

Comment: Could you please make your code compiable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages?

Comment: You wrote, "I need a resizebox". Why? For that matter, why do you need to use a `threeparttable` environment? Your code contains no `\tnote` directives, while the only valid reason for using a `tablenotes` environment is to provide the footnote material to go with the `\tnote` markers.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend to not use `resizebox` on your tabulars. This will give you a font size that is even smaller than tiny in your case.

Answer (score 3):

Here are five different versions of your table:

In the first version of the table, I have just removed the `threeparttable` environment. This causes the `tablenotes` to spread across the width of all three tabulars. However, I'd not recommend this solution as it keeps the `resizebox` and gives you, as you can see from the following screenshot, inconsistent and illegibly small font sizes:

[image]

---

In the second example, I have removed the `resizebox` and manually decreased to font size to `tiny`. In order to make the tables narrower, I have also decreased the horizontal white space between adjacent columns. As you can see from the following screenshot, the font is a bit larger than in the first example, however, still too small (as least in my opinion):

[image]

---

To be able to use a larger font, I have therefore allowed a linebreak between the second and third table in the third example. The tablenotes are still as wide as the combined width of the first two tables:

[image]

---

Here is a slightly different variant that places the tablenotes next to the third table. In this example, I have also replaced your `\hline` commands and empty rows with the rules from the `booktabs` package:

[image]

---

Lastly, your table could also fit into a portrait page as shown in the following screenshot. Here I have used a `scriptsize` font as well as the `booktabs` package:

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%%%%% Example 1 %%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\caption{Caption of the Table}  
%\begin{threeparttable}[]
\centering \tiny
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{lccccc} \hline \hline
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Subtable Name} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
LOSSFNK & 0.648* & 0.613 & 0.724** & 0.648* & 1.255 \\
& (0.337) & (0.580) & (0.360) & (0.364) & (1.053) \\
Observations & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 \\
R-squared & 0.047 & 0.051 & 0.050 & 0.049 & 0.055 \\ 
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
LOSSFNK & 0.050** & 0.048* & 0.051** & 0.047** & 0.021 \\
& (0.021) & (0.028) & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.041) \\
Observations & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 \\
R-squared & 0.080 & 0.083 & 0.082 & 0.081 & 0.086 \\        
& & & & & \\ \hline 
& & & & & \\ 
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ \hline \hline
\end{tabular}
%\hfill
\begin{tabular}{lccccc} \hline \hline
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Subtable Name} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
LOSSFNK & 0.457 & -0.318 & 0.570* & 0.649* & 1.011 \\
& (0.309) & (0.535) & (0.325) & (0.348) & (0.806) \\
Observations & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 \\
R-squared & 0.045 & 0.049 & 0.048 & 0.047 & 0.053 \\ 
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
LOSSFNK & 0.044** & 0.020 & 0.042** & 0.046** & -0.017 \\
& (0.019) & (0.022) & (0.019) & (0.022) & (0.027) \\
Observations & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 \\
R-squared & 0.084 & 0.087 & 0.086 & 0.085 & 0.091 \\    
& & & & & \\ \hline 
& & & & & \\    
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ \hline \hline
\end{tabular}
%\hfill
\begin{tabular}{lccccc} \hline \hline
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Subtable Name} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
LOSSFNK & 0.066 & -0.777 & 0.182 & 0.481 & 1.795 \\
& (0.467) & (0.856) & (0.486) & (0.549) & (1.263) \\
Observations & 204,520 & 204,520 & 204,520 & 204,520 & 204,520 \\
R-squared & 0.028 & 0.036 & 0.033 & 0.032 & 0.045 \\ 
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
LOSSFNK & 0.045** & 0.044 & 0.044** & 0.044* & 0.048 \\
& (0.021) & (0.032) & (0.021) & (0.024) & (0.052) \\
Observations & 261,101 & 261,101 & 261,101 & 261,101 & 261,101 \\
R-squared & 0.062 & 0.069 & 0.065 & 0.065 & 0.075 \\    
& & & & & \\ \hline
& & & & & \\ 
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ \hline \hline
\end{tabular}
}
%\end{threeparttable}
%\begin{tablenotes}
\small \raggedright
There should be some table notes here that go across all three subtables and not cutoff in the middle There should be some table notes here that go across all three subtables and not cutoff in the middle 
%\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}


%%%%% Example 2 %%%%%

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\caption{Caption of the Table}  
%\begin{threeparttable}[]
\centering \tiny \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
%\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{lccccc} \hline \hline
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Subtable Name} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
LOSSFNK & 0.648* & 0.613 & 0.724** & 0.648* & 1.255 \\
& (0.337) & (0.580) & (0.360) & (0.364) & (1.053) \\
Observations & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 \\
R-squared & 0.047 & 0.051 & 0.050 & 0.049 & 0.055 \\ 
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
LOSSFNK & 0.050** & 0.048* & 0.051** & 0.047** & 0.021 \\
& (0.021) & (0.028) & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.041) \\
Observations & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 \\
R-squared & 0.080 & 0.083 & 0.082 & 0.081 & 0.086 \\        
& & & & & \\ \hline 
& & & & & \\ 
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ \hline \hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{lccccc} \hline \hline
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Subtable Name} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
LOSSFNK & 0.457 & -0.318 & 0.570* & 0.649* & 1.011 \\
& (0.309) & (0.535) & (0.325) & (0.348) & (0.806) \\
Observations & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 \\
R-squared & 0.045 & 0.049 & 0.048 & 0.047 & 0.053 \\ 
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
LOSSFNK & 0.044** & 0.020 & 0.042** & 0.046** & -0.017 \\
& (0.019) & (0.022) & (0.019) & (0.022) & (0.027) \\
Observations & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 \\
R-squared & 0.084 & 0.087 & 0.086 & 0.085 & 0.091 \\    
& & & & & \\ \hline 
& & & & & \\    
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ \hline \hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{lccccc} \hline \hline
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Subtable Name} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
LOSSFNK & 0.066 & -0.777 & 0.182 & 0.481 & 1.795 \\
& (0.467) & (0.856) & (0.486) & (0.549) & (1.263) \\
Observations & 204,520 & 204,520 & 204,520 & 204,520 & 204,520 \\
R-squared & 0.028 & 0.036 & 0.033 & 0.032 & 0.045 \\ 
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
LOSSFNK & 0.045** & 0.044 & 0.044** & 0.044* & 0.048 \\
& (0.021) & (0.032) & (0.021) & (0.024) & (0.052) \\
Observations & 261,101 & 261,101 & 261,101 & 261,101 & 261,101 \\
R-squared & 0.062 & 0.069 & 0.065 & 0.065 & 0.075 \\    
& & & & & \\ \hline
& & & & & \\ 
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ \hline \hline
\end{tabular}
%}
%\end{threeparttable}
%\begin{tablenotes}
\tiny \raggedright
 There should be some table notes here that go across all three subtables and not cutoff in the middle There should be some table notes here that go across all three subtables and not cutoff in the middle 
%\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}


%%%%% Example 3 %%%%%


\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\caption{Caption of the Table}  
\centering
%\begin{threeparttable}[]
\footnotesize %\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
%\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{lccccc} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Subtable Name} \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\ \midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.648* & 0.613 & 0.724** & 0.648* & 1.255 \\
& (0.337) & (0.580) & (0.360) & (0.364) & (1.053) \\
Observations & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 \\
R-squared & 0.047 & 0.051 & 0.050 & 0.049 & 0.055 \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\ \midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.050** & 0.048* & 0.051** & 0.047** & 0.021 \\
& (0.021) & (0.028) & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.041) \\
Observations & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 \\
R-squared & 0.080 & 0.083 & 0.082 & 0.081 & 0.086 \\        
\midrule
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Subtable Name} \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\ \midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.648* & 0.613 & 0.724** & 0.648* & 1.255 \\
& (0.337) & (0.580) & (0.360) & (0.364) & (1.053) \\
Observations & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 \\
R-squared & 0.047 & 0.051 & 0.050 & 0.049 & 0.055 \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\ \midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.050** & 0.048* & 0.051** & 0.047** & 0.021 \\
& (0.021) & (0.028) & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.041) \\
Observations & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 \\
R-squared & 0.080 & 0.083 & 0.082 & 0.081 & 0.086 \\        
\midrule
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{lccccc} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Subtable Name} \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\ \midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.648* & 0.613 & 0.724** & 0.648* & 1.255 \\
& (0.337) & (0.580) & (0.360) & (0.364) & (1.053) \\
Observations & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 \\
R-squared & 0.047 & 0.051 & 0.050 & 0.049 & 0.055 \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\ \midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.050** & 0.048* & 0.051** & 0.047** & 0.021 \\
& (0.021) & (0.028) & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.041) \\
Observations & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 \\
R-squared & 0.080 & 0.083 & 0.082 & 0.081 & 0.086 \\        
\midrule
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%}
%\end{threeparttable}
%\begin{tablenotes}

\scriptsize \raggedright
 There should be some table notes here that go across all three subtables and not cutoff in the middle There should be some table notes here that go across all three subtables and not cutoff in the middle 
%\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}


%%%%% Example 4 %%%%%

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\caption{Caption of the Table}  
%\begin{threeparttable}[]
\footnotesize %\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
%\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{lccccc} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Subtable Name} \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\ \midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.648* & 0.613 & 0.724** & 0.648* & 1.255 \\
& (0.337) & (0.580) & (0.360) & (0.364) & (1.053) \\
Observations & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 \\
R-squared & 0.047 & 0.051 & 0.050 & 0.049 & 0.055 \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\ \midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.050** & 0.048* & 0.051** & 0.047** & 0.021 \\
& (0.021) & (0.028) & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.041) \\
Observations & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 \\
R-squared & 0.080 & 0.083 & 0.082 & 0.081 & 0.086 \\        
\midrule
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Subtable Name} \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\ \midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.648* & 0.613 & 0.724** & 0.648* & 1.255 \\
& (0.337) & (0.580) & (0.360) & (0.364) & (1.053) \\
Observations & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 \\
R-squared & 0.047 & 0.051 & 0.050 & 0.049 & 0.055 \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\ \midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.050** & 0.048* & 0.051** & 0.047** & 0.021 \\
& (0.021) & (0.028) & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.041) \\
Observations & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 \\
R-squared & 0.080 & 0.083 & 0.082 & 0.081 & 0.086 \\        
\midrule
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lccccc} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Subtable Name} \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\ \midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.648* & 0.613 & 0.724** & 0.648* & 1.255 \\
& (0.337) & (0.580) & (0.360) & (0.364) & (1.053) \\
Observations & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 \\
R-squared & 0.047 & 0.051 & 0.050 & 0.049 & 0.055 \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\ \midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.050** & 0.048* & 0.051** & 0.047** & 0.021 \\
& (0.021) & (0.028) & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.041) \\
Observations & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 \\
R-squared & 0.080 & 0.083 & 0.082 & 0.081 & 0.086 \\        
\midrule
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%}
%\end{threeparttable}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.625\textwidth}
%\begin{tablenotes}
\scriptsize \raggedright
 There should be some table notes here that go across all three subtables and not cutoff in the middle There should be some table notes here that go across all three subtables and not cutoff in the middle 
%\end{tablenotes}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}



%%%%% Example 5 %%%%%

%\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}[]
\caption{Caption of the Table}
\scriptsize
%\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{lccccc} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Subtable Name} \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\ \midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.648* & 0.613 & 0.724** & 0.648* & 1.255 \\
& (0.337) & (0.580) & (0.360) & (0.364) & (1.053) \\
Observations & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 \\
R-squared & 0.047 & 0.051 & 0.050 & 0.049 & 0.055 \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\ \midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.050** & 0.048* & 0.051** & 0.047** & 0.021 \\
& (0.021) & (0.028) & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.041) \\
Observations & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 \\
R-squared & 0.080 & 0.083 & 0.082 & 0.081 & 0.086 \\        
\midrule
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ \bottomrule
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Subtable Name} \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\ \midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.648* & 0.613 & 0.724** & 0.648* & 1.255 \\
& (0.337) & (0.580) & (0.360) & (0.364) & (1.053) \\
Observations & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 \\
R-squared & 0.047 & 0.051 & 0.050 & 0.049 & 0.055 \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\ \midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.050** & 0.048* & 0.051** & 0.047** & 0.021 \\
& (0.021) & (0.028) & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.041) \\
Observations & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 \\
R-squared & 0.080 & 0.083 & 0.082 & 0.081 & 0.086 \\        
\midrule
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ \bottomrule
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Subtable Name} \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\ \midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.648* & 0.613 & 0.724** & 0.648* & 1.255 \\
& (0.337) & (0.580) & (0.360) & (0.364) & (1.053) \\
Observations & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 \\
R-squared & 0.047 & 0.051 & 0.050 & 0.049 & 0.055 \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\ \midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.050** & 0.048* & 0.051** & 0.047** & 0.021 \\
& (0.021) & (0.028) & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.041) \\
Observations & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 \\
R-squared & 0.080 & 0.083 & 0.082 & 0.081 & 0.086 \\        
\midrule
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%}
\end{threeparttable} 
\begin{tablenotes} \scriptsize
\item There should be some table notes here that go across all three subtables and not cutoff in the middle 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}
%\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: isn't this to much examples for one answer ? :-) :-) :-)  +1!

Comment: If you remove the `threeparttable` "wrapper" (which I also recommend), you might as well also remove the `tablenotes` wrapper (and its no-longer-needed `\item` directives).

Comment: @Mico: You are definitely right with your comment about the tablenotes. I will incorporate it in my answer later today.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, you're not using the machinery of the `threeparttable` package appropriately. For sure, when using the `threeparttable` package, the `tablenotes` environment should be placed inside, rather than outside, the `threeparttable` environment. No exceptions.

A more fundamental issue is, why use a `threeparttable` environment in the first place for the material at hand? None of the `tabular` environments contain any `\tnote` directives. If there are no table notes to process, why set up `tablenotes` and `threeparttable` environments?

Here are some suggestions.

- Drop the `threeparttable`-related code entirely, and concentrate on making the three `tabular` environments more readable. And whatever else you do: Don't use a `\resizebox` directive to willy-nilly shoehorn the material into the width of the (rotated) text block.
- Instead, focus on improving the overall organization or exposition of the material. Usual visual cues to your advantage. In the following example, I've chosen to use three `subtable` environments, one per tabular environment, to give structure to the material.
- The three tables shown below employ three different "looks". I prefer the ones on the left and right, but you may prefer look of the one in the center. Note that even the table in center is much streamlined compared with what's done in your code.
- The code also uses `tabular*` instead of `tabular` environments, to help remove the guesswork about how wide the intercolumn whitespaces should be.
- If the main font size of your document is 12pt, you should change `\small` to `\footnotesize` in the code below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{threeparttable,pdflscape,booktabs,subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\small  % use '\footnotesize' if document font size is 12pt
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out intercol. whitespace

\caption{Caption of the Table}    

\begin{subtable}[t]{0.32\linewidth}
\subcaption{First Subtable}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lccccc@{}} 
\toprule
Panel A\\
LOSSFNK & 0.648* & 0.613 & 0.724** & 0.648* & 1.255 \\
& (0.337) & (0.580) & (0.360) & (0.364) & (1.053) \\
Obs. & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 \\
$R^2$ & 0.047 & 0.051 & 0.050 & 0.049 & 0.055 \\ 
\addlinespace\addlinespace
Panel B \\
LOSSFNK & 0.050** & 0.048* & 0.051** & 0.047** & 0.021 \\
& (0.021) & (0.028) & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.041) \\
Obs. & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 \\
$R^2$ & 0.080 & 0.083 & 0.082 & 0.081 & 0.086 \\        
\addlinespace\addlinespace 
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}
\hfill
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.32\linewidth}
\subcaption{Second Subtable}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lccccc@{}} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\
\midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.648* & 0.613 & 0.724** & 0.648* & 1.255 \\
& (0.337) & (0.580) & (0.360) & (0.364) & (1.053) \\
Obs. & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 \\
$R^2$ & 0.047 & 0.051 & 0.050 & 0.049 & 0.055 \\ 
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\
\midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.050** & 0.048* & 0.051** & 0.047** & 0.021 \\
& (0.021) & (0.028) & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.041) \\
Obs. & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 \\
$R^2$ & 0.080 & 0.083 & 0.082 & 0.081 & 0.086 \\        
\midrule  
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}
\hfill
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.32\linewidth}
\subcaption{Third Subtable}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lccccc@{}} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A} \\
\addlinespace%\midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.648* & 0.613 & 0.724** & 0.648* & 1.255 \\
& (0.337) & (0.580) & (0.360) & (0.364) & (1.053) \\
Obs. & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 & 508,578 \\
$R^2$ & 0.047 & 0.051 & 0.050 & 0.049 & 0.055 \\ 
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B} \\
\addlinespace%\midrule
LOSSFNK & 0.050** & 0.048* & 0.051** & 0.047** & 0.021 \\
& (0.021) & (0.028) & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.041) \\
Obs. & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 & 695,035 \\
$R^2$ & 0.080 & 0.083 & 0.082 & 0.081 & 0.086 \\        
\addlinespace%\midrule  
Model 1 & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 2 & Yes & Yes  & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Model 3 &  & Yes  &  &  &  \\
Model 4 &  &  & Yes  &  & \\
Model 5 &  &  &  & Yes  & \\
Model 6 &  &  &  &  & Yes \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}    

\medskip
There should be some table notes here that go across all three subtables and not cutoff in the middle 
%\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A variant where the first column of tables is only at the first table (separated by `@{\quad}` with own horizontal rules (`\cmidrule(r){1-1}`). For other columns in tables are used `S` column types. Similarly as @Mico I don't see reasonable reason why you should use ˙threeparttable˙:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{booktabse}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out inter column spaces
    \caption{Caption of the Table}
\begin{tabular*}{0.32\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                             l@{\quad} 
                        *{5}{S[table-format=1.3,
                             input-symbols=( ),
                             table-space-text-pre=(,
                             table-space-text-post=**]}
                            }
        &   \multicolumn{5}{c}{First case}                          \\
    \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-6}        
        &   \multicolumn{5}{c}{Panel A}                             \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule{2-6}
LOSSFNK & 0.648*    & 0.613     & 0.724**   & 0.648*    & 1.255     \\
        & (0.337)   & (0.580)   & (0.360)   & (0.364)   & (1.053)   \\
Obser.  & {508,578} & {508,578} & {508,578} & {508,578} & {508,578} \\
$R^2$   & 0.047     & 0.051     & 0.050     & 0.049     & 0.055     \\
    \addlinespace
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Panel B} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule{2-6}
LOSSFNK &  0.050**  &  0.048*   &  0.051**  &  0.047**  &  0.021    \\
        & (0.021)   & (0.028)   & (0.021)   & (0.023)   & (0.041)   \\
Obser.  & {695,035} & {695,035} & {695,035} & {695,035} & {695,035} \\
$R^2$   &  0.080    &  0.083    &  0.082    &  0.081    &  0.086    \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule{2-6}
Model 1 & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     \\    
Model 2 & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     \\  
Model 3 &           & {Yes}     &           &           &           \\  
Model 4 &           &           & {Yes}     &           &           \\ 
Model 5 &           &           &           & {Yes}     &           \\
Model 6 &           &           &           &           & {Yes}     \\
    \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](r){1-1}\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-6}
\end{tabular*}
    \hfil
\begin{tabular*}{0.32\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                      *{5}{S[table-format=1.3,
                             input-symbols=( ),
                             table-space-text-pre=(,
                             table-space-text-post=**]}
                            }
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Second case}                             \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]                               
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Panel A}                                 \\
    \midrule
 0.050**    & 0.048*    &  0.051**  &  0.047**  &  0.021    \\
(0.021)     & (0.028)   & (0.021)   & (0.023)   & (0.041)   \\
{695,035}   & {695,035} & {695,035} & {695,035} & {695,035} \\
 0.080      & 0.083     & 0.082     & 0.081     & 0.086     \\
    \addlinespace
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Panel B} \\
    \midrule
0.050**     &  0.048*   &  0.051**  &  0.047**  &  0.021    \\
(0.021)     & (0.028)   & (0.021)   & (0.023)   & (0.041)   \\
{695,035}   & {695,035} & {695,035} & {695,035} & {695,035} \\
0.080       &  0.083    &  0.082    &  0.081    &  0.086    \\
    \midrule
{Yes}       & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     \\
{Yes}       & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     \\
            & {Yes}     &           &           &           \\
            &           & {Yes}     &           &           \\
            &           &           & {Yes}     &           \\
            &           &           &           & {Yes}     \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{tabular*}
    \hfil
\begin{tabular*}{0.32\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                      *{5}{S[table-format=1.3,
                             input-symbols=( ),
                             table-space-text-pre=(,
                             table-space-text-post=**]}
                            }
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Third case}                              \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]                               
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Panel A}                                 \\
    \midrule
 0.648*     &  0.613    &  0.724**  &  0.648*   &  1.255    \\
(0.337)     & (0.580)   & (0.360)   & (0.364)   & (1.053)   \\
{508,578}   & {508,578} & {508,578} & {508,578} & {508,578} \\
 0.047      & 0.051     & 0.050     & 0.049     & 0.055     \\
    \addlinespace
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Panel B} \\
     \midrule
0.050**     &  0.048*   &  0.051**  &  0.047**  &  0.021    \\
(0.021)     & (0.028)   & (0.021)   & (0.023)   & (0.041)   \\
{695,035}   & {695,035} & {695,035} & {695,035} & {695,035} \\
 0.080      &  0.083    &  0.082    &  0.081    &  0.086    \\
    \midrule
{Yes}       & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     \\
{Yes}       & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     \\
            & {Yes}     &           &           &           \\
            &           & {Yes}     &           &           \\
            &           &           & {Yes}     &           \\
            &           &           &           & {Yes}     \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{tabular*}

%\raggedrigh % in case that you like to have notes left aligned
There should be some table notes that can  go across all three sub tables
\end{table}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]